# Can moderators move and change comments?

Tags: support, comments, convert-to-comment

In this question [What is a good password manager that works well with Chrome?](https://superuser.com/questions/343038/what-is-a-good-password-manager-that-works-well-with-chrome) *somebody* (I don't remember the name) answered my question. I responded with a comment. Now I see that answer and my comment **as comments in my question.** To clarify - the first comment in there signed by Rook wasn't placed there by me.

I knew moderators could delete comments, can they also move them across as well. Change their contents while them still being signed by me?

Answer (score 5):

♦ moderators can 'convert answers to comments'.

In fact, I just converted [James Litewski](https://superuser.com/users/73743/james-litewski)'s post to a comment, and I migrated your comment as well.

And yes, we can edit comments as well.

Comment: Good to know. *Creeeeepy*, though.